# Reference a Named Calculation from another Named Calculation

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssas

Is it possible to use the value for a row from a named calculation as part of the T-SQL for another named calculation?

I am using BIDS to modify a data source view for a SS 2005 SSAS cube I have. I use a named calculation to associate the AccountID to each row in another table:

```
(SELECT c.ACCOUNTID FROM sysdba.CONTACT c WHERE c.CID ={current-table}.CID)
```

These calculations run in a few seconds. If I have another named calculation that nests that command, it runs very slow, it takes minutes. An example would be:

```
(SELECT a.TYPE FROM ACCOUNT a WHERE a.ACCOUNTID = (SELECT c.ACCOUNTID FROM sysdba.CONTACT c WHERE c.CID ={current-table}.CID))
```

Is there some way to execute something like:

```
(SELECT a.TYPE FROM ACCOUNT a WHERE a.ACCOUNTID = {current-table}.AccountID)
```

Obviously, that doesn't work when I try it. It tells me that it's an invalid column ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
SELECT a.TYPE 
FROM ACCOUNT a 
JOIN sysdba.CONTACT c ON a.ACCOUNTID = c.ACCOUNTID
WHERE c.CID ={current-table}.CID
```

Comment: That throws:
> Deferred prepare could not be completed. Statement(s) could not be prepared. Incorrect syntax near the
keyword 'from'.

I tried INNER JOIN instead of JOIN FROM, but that's also very slow.